# Selecting multiple values from a join depending on another value in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, join, sqlalchemy

I have a fairly heavy query in SQLAlchemy and I'm trying to optimise it a bit, but I'm struggling with the joins as it's not something I have much knowledge in. My very small test showed the selects were 7x slower than the joins, so it'll potentially be quite a speed increase.

Here are the relevant tables and their relationships:

- `ActionInfo (id, session_id = SessionInfo.id)`
- `SessionInfo (id)`
- `SessionLink (info_id = SessionInfo.id, data_id = SessionData.id)`
- `SessionData (id, key, value)`

I basically want to read `SessionData.value` where `SessionData.key` equals something, from a select of `ActionInfo`.

Here is the current way I've been doing things:

```
stmt = select(
    ActionInfo.id,
    select(SessionData.value).where(
        SessionData.key == 'username',
        SessionLink.data_id == SessionData.id,
        SessionLink.info_id == ActionInfo.session_id,
    ).label('username'),
    select(SessionData.value).where(
        SessionData.key == 'country',
        SessionLink.data_id == SessionData.id,
        SessionLink.info_id == ActionInfo.session_id,
    ).label('country'),
)
```

In doing the above mentioned speed test, I got a single join working, but I'm obviously limited to only 1 value via this method:

```
stmt = select(
    ActionInfo.id,
    SessionData.value.label('country')
).filter(
    SessionData.key == 'country'
).outerjoin(SessionInfo).outerjoin(SessionLink).outerjoin(SessionData)
```

How would I adapt it to end up something like this?

```
stmt = select(
    ActionInfo.id,
    select(SessionData.value).where(SessionData.key=='username').label('username'),
    select(SessionData.value).where(SessionData.key=='country').label('country'),
).outerjoin(SessionInfo).outerjoin(SessionLink).outerjoin(SessionData)
```

If it's at all helpful, this is the join code as generated by SQLAlchemy:

```
SELECT action_info.id
FROM action_info LEFT OUTER JOIN session_info ON session_info.id = action_info.session_id LEFT OUTER JOIN session_link ON session_info.id = session_link.info_id LEFT OUTER JOIN session_data ON session_data.id = session_link.data_id
```

As a side note, I'm assuming I want a left outer join because I want to still include any records with missing `SessionData` records. Once I have this working though I'll test what difference an inner join makes to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below:

```
keys = ["username", "country", "gender"]
q = select(ActionInfo.id).join(SessionInfo)
for key in keys:
    SD = aliased(SessionData)
    SL = aliased(SessionLink)
    q = (
        q.outerjoin(SL, SessionInfo.id == SL.info_id)
        .outerjoin(SD, and_(SL.data_id == SD.id, SD.key == key))
        .add_columns(SD.value.label(key))
    )
```

is generic and can be extended to different number of fields, and should generate SQL similar to below:

```
SELECT action_info.id,
       session_data_1.value AS username,
       session_data_2.value AS country,
       session_data_3.value AS gender

FROM   action_info

JOIN   session_info ON session_info.id = action_info.session_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN session_link AS session_link_1 ON session_info.id = session_link_1.info_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN session_data AS session_data_1 ON session_link_1.data_id = session_data_1.id
    AND session_data_1.key = :key_1

LEFT OUTER JOIN session_link AS session_link_2 ON session_info.id = session_link_2.info_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN session_data AS session_data_2 ON session_link_2.data_id = session_data_2.id
    AND session_data_2.key = :key_2

LEFT OUTER JOIN session_link AS session_link_3 ON session_info.id = session_link_3.info_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN session_data AS session_data_3 ON session_link_3.data_id = session_data_3.id
    AND session_data_3.key = :key_3
```

Comment: Thanks, almost there, but it's not filtering by `SessionData.key`, so it is returning 3 of the same item. It's 3am now but I'll check out the [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html?highlight=aliased#sqlalchemy.orm.util.AliasedClass) on `aliased` tomorrow, looks promising if I can get my head around it :)

Comment: Right, edited to add the filter which i missed originally.

Comment: Your edit doesn't actually work, it just returns `None` for each value. However, doing `.where(SD.key == key)` works perfectly, so thanks for the help :)

Comment: This is strange as those two should be equivalent, but important is that your problem is solved.